# Asp.net:System.Security.SecurityException

Tags: asp.net, security

Thanks for any help offered. I deployed my application in server and I am getting following error while trying to access the website. Its been 2 hrs of research and stil no luck. Exception details area as follows

**Security Exception**

**Description:** The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

**Exception Details:** System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

**Source Error:**

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack Trace:**

```
[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
   System.Reflection.Assembly._GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +0
   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError) +36
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildResultCompiledType.GetPreservedAttributes(PreservationFileReader pfr) +54
   System.Web.Compilation.PreservationFileReader.ReadFileInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, String preservationFile, Int64 hashCode) +496
   System.Web.Compilation.PreservationFileReader.ReadBuildResultFromFile(VirtualPath virtualPath, String preservationFile, Int64 hashCode) +91
   System.Web.Compilation.DiskBuildResultCache.GetBuildResult(String cacheKey, VirtualPath virtualPath, Int64 hashCode) +66
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetBuildResultFromCacheInternal(String cacheKey, Boolean keyFromVPP, VirtualPath virtualPath, Int64 hashCode) +176
   System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean isPrecompiledApp) +65
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax() +51
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +337
```

Comment: Did you host your content on a UNC share? Secondly can check properties of precompiled dll’ (check to see if it has following security message at the bottom of the window)?

Comment: @ Amar: No we do host on UNC share.The precompiled dll'd were in blocked status. I unblocked it. But still my issue is not resolved.

Comment: Did you check this blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/narahari/archive/2010/06/03/system-security-securityexception-request-for-the-permission-of-type-system-web-aspnethostingpermission-system-version-2-0-0-0-culture-neutral-publickeytoken-b77a5c561934e089-failed.aspx

Comment: @user735647 have you restarted application after unblocked dll? Which version of IIS are you using?

Comment: @ Amar: Thansk.Let me check your blog

Comment: @Artem Koshelev: Yes. I did. I am using IIS 7

Comment: Looks like you may have the following problem (if it's not IIS7.5) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973031/why-am-i-getting-this-error-system-security-securityexception-request-for-the

Comment: I started to receive this error message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using IIS 7, follow the instructions in http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753658(v=ws.10).aspx to set the app in the appropriate trust level.

Comment: Thanks a lot. IT worked. I changed the "load user profile = True" in Application pool settings and got this error rectified. Hope this helps other with same problem :)